# Proper way to define recursive makefile for subfolders

Tags: makefile

I have a project like this:

```
main --> main.c uses tests/test.h
     |
     |_ tests (main/tests) --> test.h
               --> test1.c implementation of test.h
               --> test2.c implementation of test.h
               --> test3.c implementation of test.h
```

I currently have a makefile like this:

```
all: main.o tests/test1.o tests/test2.o tests/test3.o
        gcc -o main main.o tests/test1.o tests/test2.o tests3.o

%.o: %.c test.h
        gcc -c $< -o $@
```

But I feel that it's repetitive (say if I have multiple directories in main). Is there a better way to do this using recursive make definitions?

I'm a beginner, and I just wanted to explore different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by recursive, but I'd put all testx.o and testx.c into 2 lists(actually your default rule will pick up all .c files and compile them to .o files) this will probably do the work:

```
OBJECTS=tests/test1.o tests/test2.o tests/test3.o ...
SOURCES=test1.c test2.c test3.c ...

all: main
main: main.o $(OBJECTS)
     gcc -o $@  $(OBJECTS)
%.o: %.c test.h
     gcc -c $< -o $@
```